# Can markdown be enabled for the wordpress free plan?

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone tell me if its possible to enable markdown for writing posts in wordpress on the free plan? I think I need a plugin, and from what I can tell, you need a paid plan to be able to install plugins - is that correct?

Comment: Best thing to do would be to host the Wordpress install yourself, then you just go to `settings>writing` to enable markdown.

Comment: Ok, a bit more involved than I hoped. I just want to be able to write posts from any machine and be able to include properly formatted code snippets.

Comment: You can do that with a self-hosted Wordpress install, it's extremely easy to set up and has a ton more features than the Wordpress.com hosted version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't find the full dashboard. For example, if your wordpress link is http://helloworld.wordpress.com, you are able to find the full dashboard by using the link http://helloworld.wordpress.com/wp-admin/. Essentially, append wp-admin to the link.

Go to Settings → Writing in your dashboard, check the Markdown box.

I just enabled Markdown in my free plan wordpress.